# Show data from Firebase in Recyclerview, filtered on username - How to?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

With the following line of code I'm able to show the data under "results" of the User "Hendrik".

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users/Hendrik/results");
```

But what I want, is to show the data under "results" according to which user is logged in. I think I'm supposed to work with FirebaseAuth to check which user is currently logged in? I'm not really sure tho, anyone has any suggestions?

*Database tree*

[image]

*Inside my fragment*

```
private void setUpRecyclerView() {
        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users/Hendrik/results");

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Results> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Results>()
                .setQuery(query, Results.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new ResultAdapter(options);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (adapter != null) {
            adapter.startListening();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (adapter != null) {
            adapter.stopListening();
        }
    }
```

*My adapter*

```
public class ResultAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Results, ResultAdapter.ResultViewHolder> {

public ResultAdapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Results> options){
    super(options);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ResultViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Results model) {

    holder.datum.setText(model.getDatum());
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ResultViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.result_display_layout, parent, false);
    return new ResultViewHolder(v);
}


public static class ResultViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView datum;
    ImageView resultaat1, resultaat2, resultaat3, resultaat4;
    public ResultViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView){
        super(itemView);

        datum = itemView.findViewById(R.id.datum);
        resultaat1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.schietResultaat1);
        resultaat2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.schietResultaat2);
        resultaat3 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.schietResultaat3);
        resultaat4 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.schietResultaat4);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think I'm supposed to work with FirebaseAuth to check which user is currently logged in?

Yes. FirebaseAuth will generate unique ids for every user then you can structure your data like `Users->uid-> then details`

After that you could do this:

> But what I want, is to show the data under "results" according to which user is logged in

by get `uid` of the current logged in user from FirebaseAuth and your database query will look like this:

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(uid).child("result");
```

Comment: Do I have to manually change the values under `"users"` to `"uid"` so that the FirebaseAuth knows what to give an unique id?

Comment: After authentication you could get user id by `user_id = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();`.
Now you can set data like `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child(user_id).child("result").set(your_data);`

Comment: Cool thanks, I will look into this. New to android so sorry for asking basic stuff.

Comment: Assuming each user has a field called status with values of A, B, or C.  You only want to select status = 'A'. How can you do that ? FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").orderByChild("status").equalTo("R");